# ClickOnce System.Progress not working

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, clickonce

I am using the following code to invoke a method and run it asynchronously, providing feedback on the UI as it progresses. When I run the application within Visual Studio (in either debug or release config), the "lblSyncStatus" is updated, showing 10 different statuses over the course of a 60 second sync.

```
    public async Task SyncConfigurations()
    {
        var progressIndicator = new Progress<string>(ReportProgress);
        var repo = new SomeObject()
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        string result = string.Empty;
        bool syncCompleted = false;

        try
        {
            ReportProgress("Synchronizing user data...");
            int request = 0;
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun)
                request = await repo.Sync(progressIndicator, cts.Token);
            else
                request = await repo.Sync(progressIndicator, cts.Token, Properties.Settings.Default.ConfigLastUpdate);

            syncCompleted = true;
            result = "Synced complete.";
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            result = "Sync failed.";
            syncCompleted = false;
        }

        // Timestamp of sync.
        if (syncCompleted)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.ConfigLastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
            Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun = false;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }

        ReportProgress(result);
    }

    void ReportProgress(string message)
    {
        //Update the UI to reflect the progress value that is passed back.
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            this.lblSyncStatus.Content = "Sync in progress: " + message;
        }));
    }
```

The issue I have however is when I publish via `ClickOnce`. When I publish with `ClickOnce`, launch the app and run it, the label is never updated. I attached the VS debugger to the app process right after launching it and I can see the async threads exiting so I know the sync is taking place. The UI is just not reflecting this.

Why does the UI update properly under debug or release within the IDE, but not once it is deployed? I invoke the `SyncConfigurations` method from within the `Window_Loaded` method like such: `Task.Run(async () => await SyncConfigurations());`.

If anyone could help out with this I'd appreciate it!

**EDIT 1**

It seems that something is causing the SyncConfigurations to fail when I instance a new SomeObject(). I am assuming an exception is being thrown and it is not bubbling up because of the async. I added the following code right after I invoke the method:

```
            var sync = Task.Run(async () => await SyncConfigurations());
            if (sync.Exception != null)
            {
                throw new Exception(sync.Exception.Message + "\n" + sync.Exception.StackTrace);
            }
```

No exceptions are picked up. I also receive a message from the IDE now when I try to attach that it can't attach due to it not being a debug build (ClickOnce deployed release and I don't know how to change that).

So I guess my question is, how should I debug this outside of the IDE, where it seems to fail, and if am I handling the exceptions correctly (if one is indeed being thrown).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this. I published a build with the debug configuration, attached the debugger to the process and was able to find the exception within MyObject and fix it.

When you need to debug a `ClickOnce` app, you need to ensure your build config is set to Debug prior to publishing. Problem solved.